# how to use NgIF condition with formcontrol instead of ngModel

Tags: angular7, angular-ng-if

I want to compare my values using my `formcontrol` than using `ngModel`, when values is entered in my input box , I want to display my cancel image, so I given `userTextValue` as true inside subscribe, my query now is how to reset the value when cancel is clicked . I want the input box to be empty , now cancel button is hidden but still values available, I am using pipe to filter values.

```
<input matInput class="form-control input" placeholder="Enter name or Id" id="user"
    [formControl]="userControl"[matAutocomplete]="auto>
       <img src="assets/icons/cancel.svg" *ngIf="userTextvalue" class="cancel-icon" 
        aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearUserValues()">
```

ts:

```
  constructor() {
    this.userControl.valueChanges.subscribe((user) => {
      this.filterResult = user;
      this.userTextvalue = true;
    });
  }
  clearUserValues() { 
    this.filterResult = "";
    this.userTextvalue = false;
  }
```

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterUser'
})
export class FilterUserPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (searchText && searchText.length > 1) {
      items = searchText ? this.filterUsers(items, searchText) : items.slice();
    } else {
      items = [];
    }
    return items;
  }

  filterUsers(items: any[], value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All you have to get knowledge about what is difference between template driven and reactive form approach. When any change happens in formcontrol, it return new object of form (included its formcontrols) and that's what make it synchronous approach.
Let me wrap up this in short scenario.

When any change happens in formcontrol input or html tag
it could be tracked by subscribed it.
for example 
// getting specific FormControl changed value.
// form: FormGroup

```
this.form.get('name of your formControl').subscribe(value => {// here (value) is changed value of that particular formControl. });
```

2nd Approach 
For example you have formcontrol on any clickable input button or select input.
then you can emit an method on event click and on that method you can subscribe changed value and compare or save it to where you want.
sample code ::::

`<mat-select formControlName="transferType">
<mat-option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of transferTypes" (click)="onChanges()">{{type}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>`

i am calling "onChanges()" method when i selects an option then i am subscribing this formControl and getting changed value and compare selected value by comparing operation.

same as you can get changed value and then set it to any boolean type variable then you can set any div with `*ngIf=""` statement in your html template/

if any confusion let me know.
Thanks..

## angular7 #reactiveforms #formcontrol

Comment: Sorry , my question wasnt posted properly , Code was hidden . Pls see my updated query and help me out

Comment: You need to subscribe changed value in a separate method i.e "onchanges()" which will be called in onInit method. as i said in first reply if anything changes in reactive form then angular will return object which contains forms new states(Your changed value included).

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon Can you please tell me, why are you not using this `formControlName` directive ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i'm not completely sure why you want to use the filter since you have not shown the code. However, if you want to just reset your control, change `this.filterResult = ""` to `this.userControl.setValue('')` in  `clearUserValues()` method.

Also, since you are subscribing to the valueChanges, it would be better if you do it in `ngOnInit()`.

Check stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6vuh2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Your TS code will be like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.onchanges();}

onchanges() {
this.form.get('userControl').valueChanges.subscribe( data => {
    // here you can set your boolean value for condition to show cancel button
     and push the value/or object which you take from input textbox in an your array for further comparison. 
});}

  clearUserValues() { 
  // here you will be set your boolean for hiding cancel button 
  and then you will be set empty state to your formControl input by doing like this.
  this.form.get('userControl').patchValue(//here you will be pass empty string '' or what ever you want set it to.);}
```